# jQuery click doesnt work on appended div's

Tags: jquery, click, append

I would like to append a div when clicking on an image. That works fine and it looks very good. But now I have to buttons to confirm if you want to delete an item or not. I'm trying to do a clickevent on the ' yes'  button. Nothing seems to happen. How can I solve this problem?

```
$(".trashbinPage img").one('click', function(){
    $('#deletePage').closest('tr').after('<div class="deleteMessage"><p>Weet u het zeker?</p></div>');
    $('.deleteMessage').append('<div id="wrapButtons"><div class="trashYes">Ja</div><div class="trashNo">Nee</div></div>');
});

$(".trashYes").click(function(){
    alert('hoi');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Register your `.trashYes` with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.deleteMessage').on('click', '.trashYes', function() {
    ...
});
```

**Update**

In versions of `jQuery` < 1.7 you should use the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function:

**Update 2**

[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066309/125629) pointed out a problem in my code so I updated the answer.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to realize the problem is with the 2nd click handler (and narrowly beating me to the answer)

Comment: This will not work for elements appended after load, you have not delegated the event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It will for `jQuery` 1.7 and up? See [on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Incorrect, you need to pass a second parameter as the selector the element the event will fire on, eg `$('.staticParent').on('click', '.dynamicChild', fn);`. See my answer for a full example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh shoot, yeah you are spot on. My mistake, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must bind the event to the objects after you append them. Or use live() or delegate() instead of bind.
There should be a lot of articles on Internet about difference between bind, live and delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The element is being appended after page load, which is when `click()` hooks up the event. Therefore you need to use `on` with a delegate to handle the event, like this:

```
$(".deleteMessage").on('click', '.trashYes', function(){
    alert('hoi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo? `.one()` should be `.on()` .

Comment: the .one() is to do the click on the trashbin once. Otherwise you can append deletemessages endlessly